# error trying to execute a modular java jar file

Tags: java, module, jar

I have a Java 11 Modular program that runs fine from the Command prompt. However, when I package it in a Jar file (Jar 11) and try to run it again I am getting "*Error: Could not find or load main class farm.vet.VetMain in module farm.vet*".
   I have enclosed an image showing the various commands I have executed from the command line. The first line shows the program running normally (no jar used). There are a few modules involved, farm.vet is the starting point with farm.vet.VetMain containing `main()`. 
   I create the Jar file - it includes the module-info files for the various modules. However when I try to run it afterwards - that's when I get the error. I then describe the Jar file and am concerned about "No module descriptor". I believe I should have something at the top of the Modular Jar file - is that the reason for my error in running the Jar?
   I have also included my directory structure ('out' is the parent directory for all my class files). 

Any help greatly appreciated, 
Seán. 
    `java -p out -m farm.vet/farm.vet.VetMain`
    `jar -cvf mods/farm.vet.jar -C out/ .`
    `added manifest`
    `adding: farm.animals/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.animals/farm/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.animals/farm/Animal.class(in = 360) (out= 246)(deflated 31%)`
    `adding: farm.animals/farm/cattle/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.animals/farm/cattle/Cattle.class(in = 829) (out= 475)(deflated 42%)`
    `adding: farm.animals/farm/cattle/Cow.class(in = 999) (out= 548)(deflated 45%)`
    `adding: farm.animals/module-info.class(in = 195) (out= 149)(deflated 23%)`
    `adding: farm.owner/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.owner/farm/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.owner/farm/owner/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.owner/farm/owner/Owner.class(in = 1569) (out= 853)(deflated 45%)`
    `adding: farm.owner/module-info.class(in = 200) (out= 148)(deflated 26%)`
    `adding: farm.vet/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.vet/farm/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.vet/farm/vet/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)`
    `adding: farm.vet/farm/vet/VetMain.class(in = 710) (out= 448)(deflated 36%)`
    `adding: farm.vet/module-info.class(in = 194) (out= 143)(deflated 26%)`
    `java -p mods -m farm.vet/farm.vet.VetMain`
    `Error: Could not find or load main class farm.vet.VetMain in module farm.vet`
    `jar --describe-module --file mods/farm.vet.jar`
    `No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.`
    `farm.vet automatic`
    `requires java.base mandated`
    `contains farm.animals`
    `contains farm.animals.farm`
    `contains farm.animals.farm.cattle`
    `contains farm.owner`
    `contains farm.owner.farm.owner`
    `contains farm.vet`
    `contains farm.vet.farm.vet`

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Learn to copy and paste from cmd.exe into code tags. Since you didn't do that, I can't easily give you the proper command as I can't paste from an image but suffice it to say, you need `jar -cfve`

Comment: Thanks for that - I will re-edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Try `jar -cvfe mods/farm.vet.jar farm.vet.VetMain -C out .`

Comment: `jar -cvfe mods/farm.vet.jar farm.vet.VetMain -C out .`  
`java -p mods -m farm.vet/farm.vet.VetMain`  
`Error: Could not find or load main class farm.vet.VetMain in module farm.vet`

Comment: What happens with the simple `java -jar mods/farm.vet.jar`?

Comment: @g00se Similar issue. My understanding is that "-jar" is for non module Jar's.

Comment: I suspect you can have only one module per JAR, since the `module-info.class` must be in the root of the JAR (is not happening here since using `-C out/` as in posted image) - From [Quick Start](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start): "*A modular JAR is a regular JAR file that has a module-info.class in its top-level directory.*" (Similar can be found in the description of the JAR tool)

Comment: *My understanding is that "-jar" is for non module Jar's.* Not sure about that (for one thing it would badly break historic java+jars) but make sure module-info is in there as per @user16320675

Comment: The one module per JAR worked a treat! Thanks a mill @user16320675!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be one module per JAR file, since `module-info.class` must be in the root of the JAR file.

Try:

```
jar -cvf mods/farm.vet.jar -C out/farm.vet/ .
jar -cvf mods/farm.owner.jar -C out/farm.owner/ .
jar -cvf mods/farm.animals.jar -C out/farm.animals/ .
```

Based on [Project Jigsaw: Module System Quick-Start Guide](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#packaging):

> A modular JAR is a regular JAR file that has a module-info.class in its top-level directory.

and [The jar Command description](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/man/jar.html#description):

> An archive becomes a modular JAR when you include a module descriptor, module-info.class, in the root of the given directories or in the root of the .jar archive.

<sup>I got a bit confused by "*root of the given diretories*" being mentioned above</sup>

Answer (score -1):

- add this argument to jar creation command: `--main-class farm.vet.VetMain`
- run the jar file using command: `java -p mods -m farm.vet`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am getting "no such file or directory". Tried several variations:
`jar -cvf mods/farm.vet.jar --main-class farm.vet.VetMain -C out/ .`
`jar -cvf mods/farm.vet.jar --main-class=out/farm.vet/farm.vet.VetMain -C out/ .`
`jar -cvf mods/farm.vet.jar --main-class=farm.vet/farm.vet.VetMain -C out/ .`
`jar -cvf mods/farm.vet.jar --main-class=out/farm.vet/farm.vet.VetMain -C out/ .`

Comment: execute the commands from the module base directory in src. Make sure all the paths are accessible all the way while running commands

Comment: Thanks for that. It has been suggested that one module per Jar may be the issue - I have several modules present and the top level directory  does not have a module-info file. I will try that first. Thanks for your help!